# Custom CTLine struct

Tags: objective-c, macos, performance, cocoa, core-text

I am creating the custom CTLine struct for my project. It is a very simple implementation because it doesn't use CFAttributeString to create line. The whole line has one color and all glyphs have equal size. But the longer CFString is, the more time it takes to create it, and it is slower than CTLineCreateWithAttributedString().

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

#define sc (CFStringRef)

    struct Line {
        CGGlyph*line_glyphs;
        CGPoint*point;
        CTFontRef font;
        int length;
    };


    typedef  struct Line* LineRef;

    LineRef create(CFStringRef str, CTFontRef font);

    @interface View : NSView
    {
        LineRef line;
        CTLineRef l;
        CTFontRef font;
        CGFontRef font2;
        CFMutableStringRef string;

    }
 @end



 #import "View.h"
    #include <time.h>


    LineRef create(CFStringRef str, CTFontRef font){

        LineRef line = malloc(sizeof(struct Line));
        long length = CFStringGetLength(str);

        CGGlyph* gl = malloc(sizeof(CGGlyph)*length);
        CGPoint* points = malloc(sizeof(CGPoint)*length);
        CGRect rects[length];
        UniChar buffer[length];
        CFStringGetCharacters(str, CFRangeMake(0, length), buffer);
        CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters(font, buffer, gl, length);
        CTFontGetBoundingRectsForGlyphs(font, kCTFontOrientationHorizontal, gl, rects, length);
        int x_offset  = 0;
        int y = 200;
        CGPoint temp;
        for(int i = 0;i<length;i++)
        {
            temp = CGPointMake(x_offset , y);
            x_offset += rects[i].size.width + (rects[i].size.width == 0)*10;

            points[i] = temp;
        }

        line->line_glyphs = gl;
        line->point = points;
        line->font = font;
        line->length = length;
        return line;
    }



    @implementation View


    -(void)awakeFromNib{
        font = CTFontCreateWithName(CFSTR("Comic Sans MS"), 30, 0);
        font2= CGFontCreateWithFontName(CFSTR("Comic Sans MS"));
        line = create(CFSTR(""), font);
        string = CFStringCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
        [[self window] makeFirstResponder:self];


    }



    -(void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)event{
        static int index = 0;

        NSString* i = [event characters];

        CFStringAppend(string,sc  i);
        CFMutableAttributedStringRef s = CFAttributedStringCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
        CFAttributedStringReplaceString(s, CFRangeMake(0, 0), string);
        CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(s, CFRangeMake(0, CFStringGetLength(string)), kCTFontAttributeName, font);
        CFAbsoluteTime t1 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
        l = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString(s);
        CFAbsoluteTime t2 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
        double d1 = t2-t1;
        CFAbsoluteTime T1 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
        line = create(string, font);
        CFAbsoluteTime T2 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
        double d2 = T2 - T1;
        printf("test:%i core text: %f       my implem : %f \n",index, d1,d2);



        index++;
    }
@end
```

And output:

```
  test:0 core text: 0.000761       my implem : 0.000016 
    test:1 core text: 0.000047       my implem : 0.000029 
    test:2 core text: 0.000041       my implem : 0.000027 
    test:3 core text: 0.000045       my implem : 0.000032 
    test:4 core text: 0.000045       my implem : 0.000032 
    test:5 core text: 0.000046       my implem : 0.000034
    ...
    test:176 core text: 0.000068     my implem : 0.000151 
    test:177 core text: 0.000084     my implem : 0.000171 
    test:178 core text: 0.000099     my implem : 0.000230 
    test:179 core text: 0.000061     my implem : 0.000145 
    test:180 core text: 0.000071     my implem : 0.000224 
    test:181 core text: 0.000057     my implem : 0.000149
```

You see that first couple calls are faster then CTLine creation but than it starts to take more time for my implementation to do the work.
Maybe it's multiple CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters() calls fault? Can you give some advice to speed up this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr Use `CTLineCreateWithAttributedString()` where necessary and move on; there are much larger performance issues elsewhere in your pipeline. `CGContextDrawPath()` is your real nemesis.

By way of credentials, I wrote an iOS app that allows [OSM's entire dataset](https://planet.openstreetmap.org) to be rendered down and displayed on an iPhone  - all the way down to footpaths and buildings. It looks like this (note that all the little feet for the footpaths are glyphs in a font):

[image: a map tile]

My pipeline looks a little like this:

1. **Check each string's bounding box and discard if at all possible**
2. Call `CTLineCreateWithAttributedString()` on the remaining strings.
3. Iterate over each `CTRun` and use `CTFontCreatePathForGlyph()` to get each glyphs path.
4. **Check each path's bounding box and discard if at all possible.**
5. Call `CGContextDrawPath()` the remaining paths

Steps 1 and 4 are the place to optimise. Drawing wiggly lines (glyphs) is computationaly intensive, there's no way of getting around that. The only winning move is not to play [¹](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WarGames).

(For more optimising fun, take look at [MinimumRubber](https://github.com/jjrscott/MinimumRubber), specifically the `MRPathMetrics` functions which can be used to avoid expensive `CGPath` based functions)

Comment: So I should abandon the idea of creating own CTLine

Comment: Alas so; yes 

Comment: But I want to make syntax highlighting system and I don't want to layout all glyphs to only change their color

Comment: I'm afraid I can only really comment on your question as initially stated. 

However, for syntax highlighting, NSLayoutManager (both [iOS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutmanager) and [macOS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nslayoutmanager)) has methods for [Managing Temporary Attribute Support](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutmanager?language=objc#1655034) which may be of significant help to you.